# ASPNET boilerplate Get Request with complex object in input model

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I add a service in my ApplicationService class like this:

```
public async Task<object> GetTargetsLocations(MyModel model)
{
    ....
}
```

and I define in MyModel class List of Sample class like this:

```
    public class MyModel
    {
            public List<Sample> Samples{ get; set; }

    }
}

public class Sample
{
    public float item1{ get; set; }
    public float item2{ get; set; }
}
```

when I request with swagger and fill Samples property my input model always deserialize with
empty list of samples property

I also check my request url and sample property is include to it

Comment: Are you having problem only with `Samples` list?

Comment: @viveknuna yes other property in MyModel class fill properly

Comment: What is the request, could you please check?

Comment: @viveknuna  {apiurl}/GetTargetsLocations?TargetsId=1&MyModel=%7B%0A%20%20%22Sample%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22lat%22%3A%2035.87350272286552

Comment: Add [FromUri] in the method parameter

Comment: @viveknuna I test it but don't response yet

Comment: Can you Post the sample class too pls?

Comment: @Serge yes of course I update my question

Comment: @amiramirifar thanks I don't think that it is a good idea to use Get and query string to send this very complicated data. You have to think about POST

Comment: @Serge I put this way for last chance :)